# how to hide panel of a dojo splitcontainer / bordercontainer?

Tags: javascript, dojo

How to hide splitcontainer pane programmatically. I have 3 panels. i want to hide show one panel on press of a button. how to do that ? Don't want to destroy it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use SplitContainer's addChild() and removeChild() methods:

```
splitContainer.removeChild(contentPane3); // to hide pane
splitContainer.addChild(contentPane3); // to show pane
```

Follow [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/CPu2t/) to see and play with working example including toggling of panes.

Also please note, that SplitContainer is deprecated and you should use dijit.layout.BorderContainer instead. Set data-dojo-props="splitter:true" to enable drag-n-drop resizing.

Comment: It worked :) only thing we have to do is delete pane and sub-object so it does not occupy memory.